# NSPanel and beginSheet deallocs other window and view controllers

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, modal-dialog

I have a main window containing two views (corresponding controllers too), I display a NSPanel from the main window. The NSPanel is connected through IB and in my main window controller I start the modal session as following

MainWindowController.m

```
  [self.window beginSheet:sheet completionHandler:^(NSModalResponse returnCode) {
        NSLog(@"End...");
    }];
```

I ran into problems with NSNotificationCenter with observers being deallocated, so I added in all my VCs

MainWindowController.m + SomeOtherInMainWindowController.m

```
- (void)dealloc {
    NSLog(@"%s",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
}
```

and I can see them being deallocated when I display the sheet modally.
This of course yields a problem, since the other VCs are observers of notifications being posted depending on the interaction with the sheet.

Can someone shed some light about this behaviour.

## Solved

Turns out that my previous attempt to load the sheet from a separate XIB was still existent through this line of code.

```
//    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SheetWindow" owner:self topLevelObjects:nil];
```

Commenting that out resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you're not holding some strong references to your controllers, thus ARC deallocates them, most likely when an autorelease pool gets drained.

Comment: I updated the question with info about where I start the sheet. It is that same window controller that supposedly is deallocated? Seems strange that it would deallocate the parent.